# python "not enough arguments for format string"

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am trying to insert multiple rows from dataframe to mysql.

I counted arguments numbers and they all are of same number (i.e. 11 here).

But still I get this

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

Here's the function:

```
def insert_result_sets_into_db(df, filter_rule_id):

    cols = "('hash_id', 'filter_rule_id', 'task_id', 'assigned_to', 'human_verdict', 'verdict_date', 'verdict_by', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at')"

    if not df.empty:
        with connections['frontend'].cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO dmf_result_set_assign " + cols + " VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            values = []
            now = datetime.now()
            formatted_date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            # Insert DataFrame records one by one. 
            for i,row in df.iterrows():
                 tup = (row['_id'], filter_rule_id, 1, 1, 'Matched', formatted_date, 1, 1, 1, formatted_date, formatted_date)
                 values.extend(tup)

            cursor.executemany(sql, values) 

            connections.commit()
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Why do you make a raw SQL query yourself instead of using the Django ORM (or at least the `.raw()` of the Django ROM)?

Comment: I think you want `values.append(tup)`, not `.extend()`.

Comment: Django *has* support to insert elements in bulk, so there is no need to wrap your own logic here.